unable to connect to mongodb via plesk web server
I have developed a nodejs web server (api) that connects to mongodb database.
I set the mongodb NetworkAccess to be 0.0.0.0, meaning that it connects from evrywhere.
The server api is working fine without any isse from my local machine, and with free hosting on render.
Now I'm using a paid hosting on Plesk, and the server is refusing to connect: it give s me the following error from the Plesk CLI when I try to run the server:
npm run start
Process exited with non-zero exit code '1'

server@1.0.0 start
node server
server running on port 5000
MongooseServerSelectionError: Could not connect to any servers in your MongoDB Atlas cluster. One common reason is that you're trying to access the database from an IP that isn't whitelisted. Make sure your current IP address is on your Atlas cluster's IP whitelist: https://www.mongodb.com/docs/atlas/security-whitelist/
at _handleConnectionErrors (/var/www/vhosts/kws.tn/api.kws.tn/node_modules/mongoose/lib/connection.js:896:11)
at NativeConnection.openUri (/var/www/vhosts/kws.tn/api.kws.tn/node_modules/mongoose/lib/connection.js:847:11)
at async connectDB (/var/www/vhosts/kws.tn/api.kws.tn/config/db.js:5:18) {
reason: TopologyDescription {
type: 'ReplicaSetNoPrimary',
servers: Map(3) {
'cluster0-shard-00-02.c1aum.mongodb.net:27017' => [ServerDescription],
'cluster0-shard-00-01.c1aum.mongodb.net:27017' => [ServerDescription],
'cluster0-shard-00-00.c1aum.mongodb.net:27017' => [ServerDescription]
},
stale: false,
compatible: true,
heartbeatFrequencyMS: 10000,
localThresholdMS: 15,
setName: 'atlas-72cshk-shard-0',
maxElectionId: null,
maxSetVersion: null,
commonWireVersion: 0,
logicalSessionTimeoutMinutes: null
},
code: undefined
}

I added the web server IP address to the list of NetworkAccess list on mongodb atals. but still the same issue.
Below is the javascript code to connect to MongoDB:


    const mongoose = require("mongoose").set("strictQuery", false);
    const connectDB = async () => {
      try {
        const conn = await mongoose.connect(process.env.MONGODB_URI);
        console.log(`MongoDB connected: 
            ${conn.connection.host}`.cyan.underline);
      } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
        process.exit(1);
      }
    };
    module.exports = connectDB;



And here is the server.js file


require("colors");
require("dotenv").config();
const cors = require("cors");
const express = require("express");
const { errorHandler } = require("./middleware/errorMiddleware");
const connectDB = require("./config/db");
const port = process.env.PORT || 5000;

connectDB();
const app = express();
app.use(cors());
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: false }));

app.use("/api/auth", require("./routes/authRoutes"));
app.use("/api/quiz", require("./routes/quizRoutes"));
app.use("/api/users", require("./routes/userRoutes"));
app.use("/api/exams", require("./routes/examRoutes"));
app.use("/api/stats", require("./routes/statsRoutes"));
app.use("/api/courses", require("./routes/courseRoutes"));
app.use("/api/reviews", require("./routes/reviewRoutes"));
app.use("/api/questions", require("./routes/questionRoutes"));

app.use(errorHandler);

app.listen(port, () =>
  console.log(`Server running on port ${port}`.magenta.underline)
);



Here is the error handler middleware


const errorHandler = (err, req, res, next) => {
  const statusCode = res.statusCode ? res.statusCode : 500;
  res.status(statusCode);
  res.json({
    message: err.message,
    stak: process.env.NODE_ENV === "production" ? null : err.stack,
  });
};

module.exports = { errorHandler };




Can you expand the [ServerDescription] part? it should have more details in there

I added the db.js code above
